# How to tell where specific ethernet interfaces originate?

Tags: networking, network-interface

I have a Jetson Nano that has the following interfaces in `ifconfig`.

```
rndis0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 62:e5:4a:79:fd:e5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 62:e5:4a:79:fd:e7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ztbto4tsm2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 2800
        inet 172.25.242.102  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.25.255.255
        inet6 fe80::e8ec:cfff:fe69:1057  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ea:ec:cf:69:10:57  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 17297  bytes 5830391 (5.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38581  bytes 40926618 (40.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I know rndis0 and usb0 are related to a USB device. However, I see those interfaces even when no USB devices are connected. How can I investigate why/where these interfaces are created?

Separately, I know the ztbto4tsm2 interface comes from my ZeroTier VPN from deduction, however, is there a general command/method I could use to figure out that the virtual interface is created by my ZeroTier process?

Answer (score 0):

Check for a network script under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`

To view physical devices you can use the following.

`$ lsusb`
`$ lspci`

ZTO provide compiled binaries, so there is not much you can find out unless your read their source code.

Here is their linux build script:

https://github.com/zerotier/ZeroTierOne/blob/master/make-linux.mk

You can also try this:

`sudo zerotier-cli listnetworks`